# Wordpress page using ajax and pagination

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have my ajax running perfectly and now i need my pagination to work on the page. I have no idea how to start.. another problem is i need it to bring in 16 posts at a time.. PLease help

How do i change this into a next and previous pagination
html below

```
<ul id="sermonserie1">
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button load-more" page="1">Next page</a>
    <?php endwhile;?>
</ul>
```

ajax page

```
global $post, $wpdb;
if(isset($_POST['pagi'])) {
if( isset($_REQUEST["locations"]) || isset($_REQUEST["speaker"]) || isset($_REQUEST["topic"])) {
if ($_REQUEST["locations"]!='#' ) {
        $locat_termy = array('sermons', $_REQUEST['locations']);
    } else {
        $locat_termy = array('sermons');
        $locations_resource = get_term_children( 16, 'category' );
        foreach ( $locations_resource as $child_location ) {
                $location_term = get_term_by( 'id', $child_location, 'category' );
                $locat_termy[] .= $location_term->slug;
            }           
            //print_r($locations_resource);
            //print_r($locat_termy);

    }

 $all_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'resources',
        'author' => $speak, 
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array (
        'relation' => 'OR',

                            array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                            'field' => 'id',
                            'terms' =>  $topicids,
                            ),

                            array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'category',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' =>  $locat_termy,
                            ),


                    ) ,'date_query' => $thedate 
        );
        $query = new WP_Query( $all_args );
        //print_r($query);

        //$eevents = array();
        //print_r($query);

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php }
                } ?>
```

this is my js

```
jQuery('.button.load-more').live('click', function() {
    var pagenum = parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('page'))+ 1;               
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://cj.co.za/back/page/'+pagenum+'',
        data: {
            pagi:1,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#sermonserie1').append(data);
            jQuery('.button.load-more').attr('page', pagenum)
        },
        error: function() {
            jQuery('.button.load-more').text('No page');
        }
   });
```

});

Comment: SCREAMING! ALL HAIL CAPS LOCK!

Comment: QUESTION TITLE WRITTEN IN ALL CAPS - please, don't scream at us

Comment: sorry for the caps guys